# jQuery Reel enable looping animation

Tags: javascript, jquery-reel

jQuery Reel plugin out of the box when i set options `data-loops="false"` and enable animation `data-speed="1.5"` it loops sequence horizontally, but only when it goes to last vertical row of the image set.

How can i modify JS code to enable looping each horizontal (row back and forth endlessly) without auto switching to next horizontal row, only allow mouse to switch rows.

```
Goal 1. Disable switching to next row when automatically scrolling.
Goal 2. At the end of horizontal animation reverse animation for that row backwards and then forward again.
Goal 3. Optional, don't stop animation while scrolling image vertically
```

JS Fiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ufbhgws6/)

**EDIT:** Basically functionality is already there [JS Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/xLfh4ges/) only thing need to do is make it "bounce back" when animation reaches the end instead of starting from beginning, and bounce forth once reaches the start.

Comment: What is your goal? Why put `data-loops="false"` if you don't want it? I dont understand your problem...

Comment: @Roman you need to manually change the direction of the animation using trigger, added a answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some JS to make it loop clockwise then counterclockwise, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n83ytq90/53/

```js
$('#image').on('loaded', function() {
  $('#image').on('frameChange', function() {
    var row = $(this).reel('row');
    var frame = $(this).reel('frame');
    // if we reached the end of the row (frame 20 for row 1, 40 for row 2 etc)
    if (frame === 20 * row) {
    // play in reverse
      $("#image").trigger('play', [-1.5]);
    }
    // if we reach first frame of row
    if (frame === (20 * (row - 1) + 1)) {
    // play forward
      $("#image").trigger('play', [1.5]);
    }
  });
});
```